# Why doesn't changes in Eclipse Editor doesn't effekt my code?

Tags: java, eclipse

I've trying to change my code on an other device and got the code over Dropbox from the one to the other device, but when I make changes in my code the program behave the same way as before. I doesn't know why?!

```
//when collecting an Powerup-Item start a random Powerup
public static void pupHit() {

    ItemCreator.powerUp.setLocation(new Point(-50, -50));
    //usually I would generate a random number between 1 and 6 
    //with the commented 2 lines below and save it in the variable pup
    //Random rand = new Random();
    int pup = 6; //rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
    //even if I give pup a static value of 6, pup differs between 1 and 5/6
    switch(pup){
        case 1: ItemPowerups.speed(); Stats.points += 10; break;
        case 2: ItemPowerups.slow(); Stats.points += 5; break;
        case 3: ItemPowerups.lsd(); Stats.points += 15; break;
        case 4: ItemPowerups.invert(); Stats.points += 25; break;
        case 5: ItemPowerups.obstacle(); Stats.points += 10; break;
        case 6: ItemPowerups.steelJawbone(); Stats.points += 10; break;
    }   
}
```

I've tried to add `System.out.printl(pup);` after declaring and initializing `pup`. This doesn't affect my code as well.

Comment: clean and build it again..delete the classes from build/bin and then try to execute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to build it again :D.
(I know the last guy solved it but we need the question to have an answer).